# How can I subtract two IPv6 addresses (128bit numbers) in C/C++?

Tags: c++, c, networking, ipv6

I'm storing the IP address in `sockaddr_in6` which supports an array of four 32-bit, **addr[4]**. Essentially a 128 bit number.

I'm trying to calculate number of IPs in a given IPv6 range (how many IPs between). So it's a matter of subtracting one from another using two arrays with a length of four.

The problem is since there's no **128bit** data type, I can't convert into decimal.

Thanks a ton!

Comment: Practically speaking, won't all ranges be between  /32 and /96 ?

Comment: IPv6 is designed so that you always have more addresses than you'll ever need, so I hope you'll never need this code. Thinking about the number of addresses with IPv6 is usually a sign that you're still stuck in an IPv4 mindset :)

Comment: With a few exceptions, an IPv6 address range (subnet) will be a /64, and that equals 18,446,744,073,709,551,616 addresses per subnet. For other sizes, you could always calculate 2^(128-mask length).

Comment: Subtraction is the wrong solution. You've asked the wrong question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use some kind of big-int library (if you can tolerate LGPL, GMP is the choice). Fortunately, 128 bit subtraction is easy to simulate by hand if necessary. Here is a quick and dirty demonstration of computing the absolute value of (a-b), for 128 bit values:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

struct U128
{
    unsigned long long hi;
    unsigned long long lo;
};

bool subtract(U128& a, U128 b)
{
    unsigned long long carry = b.lo > a.lo;
    a.lo -= b.lo;
    unsigned long long carry2 = b.hi > a.hi || a.hi == b.hi && carry;
    a.hi -= carry;
    a.hi -= b.hi;
    return carry2 != 0;
}

int main()
{
    U128 ipAddressA = { 45345, 345345 };
    U128 ipAddressB = { 45345, 345346 };

    bool carry = subtract(ipAddressA, ipAddressB);

    // Carry being set means that we underflowed; that ipAddressB was > ipAddressA.
    // Lets just compute 0 - ipAddressA as a means to calculate the negation 
    // (0-x) of our current value. This gives us the absolute value of the
    // difference.
    if (carry)
    {
        ipAddressB = ipAddressA;
        ipAddressA = { 0, 0 };
        subtract(ipAddressA, ipAddressB);
    }

    // Print gigantic hex string of the 128-bit value
    std::cout.fill ('0');
    std::cout << std::hex << std::setw(16) << ipAddressA.hi << std::setw(16) << ipAddressA.lo << std::endl; 
}
```

This gives you the absolute value of the difference. If the range is not huge (64 bits or less), then `ipAddressA.lo` can be your answer as a simple `unsigned long long`.

If you have perf concerns, you can make use of compiler intrinsics for taking advantage of certain architectures, such as amd64 if you want it to be optimal on that processor. `_subborrow_u64` is the amd64 intrinsic for the necessary subtraction work.

Answer (score 1):

The `in6_addr` structure stores the address in network byte order - or 'big endian' - with the most significant byte @ `s6_addr[0]`. You can't count on the other union members being consistently named, or defined. Even If you accessed the union through a (non-portable) `uint32_t` field, the values would have to be converted with `ntohl`. So a *portable* method of finding the difference needs some work.

You can convert the `in6_addr` to `uint64_t[2]`. Sticking with typical 'bignum' conventions, we use [0] for the low 64-bits and [1] for the high 64-bits:

```
static inline void
in6_to_u64 (uint64_t dst[2], const struct in6_addr *src)
{
    uint64_t hi = 0, lo = 0;

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        hi = (hi << 8) | src->s6_addr[i];
        lo = (lo << 8) | src->s6_addr[i + 8];
    }

    dst[0] = lo, dst[1] = hi;
}
```

and the difference:

```
static inline unsigned int
u64_diff (uint64_t d[2], const uint64_t x[2], const uint64_t y[2])
{
    unsigned int b = 0, bi;

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        uint64_t di, xi, yi, tmp;

        xi = x[i], yi = y[i];
        tmp = xi - yi;
        di = tmp - b, bi = tmp > xi;
        d[i] = di, b = bi | (di > tmp);
    }

    return b; /* borrow flag = (x < y) */
}
```

Comment: What would've been the method if I could rely on existence of uint64_t. So, to make things simpler, I've **uint64_t addr_begin[2]** and **uint64_t addr_end[2]**, where it's guaranteed that **addr_end >= addr_begin**. How could I store the result in **uint64_t result[2]**?

Thanks a lot Brett, for your time.

Comment: @shadowyman - added examples. the u128 difference uses same subtract/borrow idea as the byte 'vector'.